# How to deal with click events in qt3d?

Tags: qt, qml, qt3d

I want to do something when click or doubleclick in the scene3d. But nothing to show in my console

```
Scene3D {
    aspects: ["logic", "input"]
    ...
    MouseDevice { id: mouse_device }
    MouseHandler {
        sourceDevice: mouse_device
        onPressed: { ... }
        onPositionChanged: { ... }
        onWheel: { ... } 
        onClicked: { console.log("click") } // failed
        onDoubleClicked: { ... } // failed
    }
    ...
}
```

Maybe I am missing something? Or is there another way to do it?

Comment: Do you want to intercept a 2D click on the 3D window or do you want to handle clicking the 3D objects? If the latter, try using [QObjectPicker](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3drender-qobjectpicker.html).

Comment: I want to intercept a 2D click on the 3D window